# Return Key Not Working For Textarea PHP/Yii

Tags: php, html, yii

The following is done using Yii and PHP already tried to ask on the Yii Forum but no solutions where given.

I have the following textArea in one of my views.

```
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_description'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'ref_description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_description'); ?>
</div>
```

Why isn't it able to return a newline when pressing the enter key but instead it's moving to the following textField?

Whole Code:

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'report-references-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'ref_name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_description'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'ref_description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_description'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_quarter'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'ref_quarter'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_quarter'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_year'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'ref_year'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_year'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ref_date'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'ref_date'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'ref_date'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Please suggest about anything as this thing looks really stupid and I can't seem to find a way around it tried javscript with shift+enter command and other things.

Comment: `Why isn't it able to return a newline when pressing the enter key but instead it's moving to the following textField` - i don't think it's related to the php code. Or you have a js code that does that or it's your browser.

Comment: I tried different browsers, it didn't work. Also it doesn't seem that there is any js code associated with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to disable all js code (webdeveloper addon for firefox for example).
2. Save to pure html page and delete particular parts. This will help you diagnose reason.
3. If below fail try to build pure html form without anything more than pure html tags. No css, no js.
4. Check your browser addons - mabye there is something.

Comment: I disabled the JS and it did it!

Answer (score 0):

For further help to this question regarding the Yii. What needs to be changed is in the main layout.

There is a javascript code:

```
    $('body').on('keydown', 'input, select' , 'textarea', function(e) {
    var self = $(this)
      , form = self.parents('form:eq(0)')
      , focusable
      , next
      ;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible:not(:disabled)');
        next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
        if (next.length) {
            next.focus();
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Remove the textarea from the $('body').on function ONLY!